# How to get min by value only in Scala Map

Tags: scala

I have a map that has `SomeClass -> Double` I want to get the `SomeClass` associated with the smallest value. How do I go about doing this? Ties do not matter and can be broken arbitrarily if that is an issue.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Use [`minBy`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/immutable/Map.html):

```
Map("a" -> 3.0, "b" -> 1.0, "c" -> 2.0).minBy(_._2)._1
```

This gives `"b"` as expected.

Answer (score 1):

Starting `Scala 2.13`, you might prefer [`minByOption`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.13.x/scala/collection/Map.html#minByOption[B](f:A=%3EB)(implicitcmp:scala.math.Ordering[B]):Option[A]) in order to also safely handle empty `Map`s:

```scala
Map("a" -> 3.0, "b" -> 1.0, "c" -> 2.0).minByOption(_._2).map(_._1)
// Some("b")
Map[String, Double]().minByOption(_._2).map(_._1)
// None
```

And you can always decide to fallback on a default value when the Map is empty:

```
Map[String, Double]().minByOption(_._2).map(_._1).getOrElse("")
```