# Scala - distinct on list, but with a pick order / priority

Tags: scala, collections

Given a list of case class:

```
case class Entity(name: String, priority: Int)
```

What's a nice way to find all the unique people, but only pick the highest priority entry (where priority 1 is considered higher than 2), so that:

```
val l = Seq(Entity("Alex",20), Entity("Alex",3), Entity("Bob", 28))
```

becomes

```
Seq(Entity("Alex", 3), Entity("Bob", 28))
```

Comment: my bad, priority is more like "rank" I suppose, where 1 > 2 > 3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- group by name, and
- sort by rank
- pick head

Example,

```
scala> case class Entity(name: String, priority: Int)
defined class Entity

scala> val input = Seq(Entity("Alex",20), Entity("Alex",3), Entity("Bob", 28), Entity("UPD", 100), Entity("UPD", 100))
input: Seq[Entity] = List(Entity(Alex,20), Entity(Alex,3), Entity(Bob,28), Entity(UPD,100), Entity(UPD,100))

scala> input.groupBy(_.name).map(_._2.sortBy(_.priority).head)
res5: scala.collection.immutable.Iterable[Entity] = List(Entity(UPD,100), Entity(Bob,28), Entity(Alex,3))
```

Efficient approach would be to get the one with minimum rank as you don't need to sort the whole sequence.

```
scala> input.groupBy(_.name).map(_._2.minBy(_.priority))
res6: scala.collection.immutable.Iterable[Entity] = List(Entity(UPD,100), Entity(Bob,28), Entity(Alex,3))
```

**Similar questions:**

[How to get min by value only in Scala Map](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8750992/432903)

[how to sort a scala.collection.Map[java.lang.String, Int] by its values?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2973045/432903)

Comment: awesome! thanks! intelliJ tells me you could further simplify it using minBy(), but thanks seriously

Comment: minBy is a nice approach actually because you only care about the minimum, so no overhead of sorting the whole sequence.